# Assign row object as field name in ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, string, syntax

Is there a specific way to assign the object that for example row[0] returns in a `SearchCursor` to a new field name? I mean how to write it in add field syntax, this doesn't work: `arcpy.AddField_management(fc, str(row[0]), "DOUBLE")`. That field is a string field by the way. I can't find such an example anywhere online. Here is the code:

```
import arcpy

fc = "C:/Users/salahmed/Documents/ArcGIS/Test.shp"

myList = []
myList2 = []
myList3 = []

myField = ["USE"]
myFields = ["USE", "Stadteil", "PERCENT"]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, myField) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
    if row[0] in myList:
        pass
    else:
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, str(row[0]), "DOUBLE")
        myList.append(row[0])
del cursor
```

Comment: What error message do you get? Are you trying to add a field inside the cursor? Could you show you code?

Comment: Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 17, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3246, in AddField     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Failed to execute (AddField).

This is the error.
And yes I am adding field inside the cursor.
I don't know how to share my code here in comments? Just copy paste?

Comment: You can edit your question to add the code. But you can't add a field inside a cursor.

Comment: Oh, that I didn't know. But I wanted to loop through the rows, collect specific values from a field and add new fields with those names. Any other way?

Comment: Just loop through your list at the end rather than in the cursor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @JamesLeversha, create a list of the fields to be added then add those fields outside the cursor:

```
import arcpy

fc = "C:/Users/salahmed/Documents/ArcGIS/Test.shp"

myList = []
myList2 = []
myList3 = []

myField = ["USE"]
myFields = ["USE", "Stadteil", "PERCENT"]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, myField) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in myList:
            pass
        else: 
            myList.append(row[0])

for f in myList:
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, f, "DOUBLE")
```

And by the way the `del` statement is useless if you use `with` to create your cursor.

Comment: Just wondering, I know the user hasn't mentioned it but should the user be concerned with if the name of the field is valid or not?

Comment: The names are just normal strings. no invalid names there. And the above method works. Thank you.

Comment: @JamesLeversha - Sure you could make all sorts of checks - is the field name valid, not too long for a shapefile, does the field already exists in the table. In this case it doesn't seem to be necessary!

Comment: @GISGe Do you mean I can use the cursor and row objects once again in the same code without using the del statement here?

Comment: @Salman the cursor will be deleted once it has passed over all the rows once. You can recreate it later if you need to pass over the rows once more.

Comment: @Salman if you want to use that section of code again later in the script then consider looking up creating a function http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm

Comment: A similar question- how can I create a dictionary which takes the row object as its name? When I simply use row[1] = {row[0]:row[2]}, it gives me an error saying that the tuple object does not support assignment. So its thinking that i'm trying to modify the actual tuple row object at its 0 index element. But no, i'm just trying to create a dictionary with the text in that field as a name.